# Mirrors repository ignored in jfrog command GitLabCi

Tags: gitlab-ci, artifactory, jfrog-cli

We have configured a monorepo in GitLab. The structure is:

```
-project1
  -pom.xml
-project2
  -pom.xml
-project3
  -pom.xml
-project4
  -pom.xml
-settings.xml
-gitlab-ci.yaml
```

The pipeline looks something like:

```
- mvn clean install -f project1/pom.xml -s settings.xml -DskipTests=true -DskipIT=true --batch-mode
- ./jfrog rt mvn "clean install -f project1/pom.xml -s settings.xml -DskipTests=true 
-DskipIT=true --batch-mode "artifactory_configuration.yml --build-name=xxxx --build-number=$CI_JOB_ID
```

Settings.xml:

```
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>ecd-central</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://repository111.int/content/groups/public-ecd-2.0-cdf</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
```

It seems that when the jfrog command is run, it ignores the mirrors, any ideas why:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:2.4.0: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:pom:2.4.0 from/to 
artifactory-release (http://swf-artifactory.int/artifactory/com.fc-snapshot): transfer failed
 for http://swf-artifactory.int/artifactory/com.fc-snapshot/org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-
plugin/2.4.0/maven-bundle-plugin-2.4.0.pom, status: 409 Conflict -> [Help 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The JFrog CLI allows you to configure Artifactory servers and repositories without using Maven's `settings.xml` file. If configured, it overrides the servers in the `settings.xml` file.

Basically, you can configure your Artifactory servers and repositories in a single CLI command and use the configuration for your build.

You can configure the servers in on of the following 2 ways:

1. **Interactive**: In your local machine, in the root workspace run `jfrog rt mvn-config`. This command creates `.jfrog/projects/maven.yaml` file which can be committed to the source code of your project.
2. **Non-interactive**: In the GitLab script, in the root workspace run:

   ```
   jfrog rt mvn-config --server-id-resolve --repo-resolve-releases= --repo-resolve-snapshots= --server-id-deploy= --repo-deploy-releases=
   ```

   The command creates `.jfrog/projects/maven.yaml` which will be used in the build command.

Ultimately, you can run your build command without providing the settings.xml file:

```
/jfrog rt mvn "clean install -f project1/pom.xml -DskipTests=true 
-DskipIT=true --batch-mode "artifactory_configuration.yml --build-name=xxxx --build-number=$CI_JOB_ID
```

Read more:

- [Running Maven Builds](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningMavenBuilds)
- [Take Full Control of Your Maven Deployments](https://jfrog.com/blog/take-full-control-of-your-maven-deployments/)
- [QuickStart Guide: Maven and Gradle](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/QuickStart+Guide%3A+Maven+and+Gradle)

Comment: You don't show how to use two resolve repos at once. If you ignore my settings.xml and my repositories section in my pom, how do I use more than one place to load dependencies.

Comment: To resolve from multiple repositories, create a virtual repository in Artifactory containing all of the repositories and use it as the resolution repository: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Virtual+Repositories

Comment: That would work for some situations but isn’t appropriate when there would end up being hundreds of specialty virtual repositories. 
It does turn out that you can leave off the two —repo-resolve options to the config call and put whatever set of repos you want in your pom or settings.xml file.